# How to use p12 client certificate with spring feign client

Tags: spring-boot, client-certificates, spring-cloud-feign

I have a Spring Boot application that calls a remote service.

This remote web service provided me a p12 file that should authenticate my application.

How do I configure my feign client to use the p12 certificate ?

---

I've tried settings these properties:

```
-Djavax.net.ssl.keyStore=path_to_cert.p12 -Djavax.net.ssl.keyStorePassword=xxx -Djavax.net.ssl.keyStoreType=PKCS12
```

But it doesn't change anything, I still get this error:

```
sun.security.provider.certpath.SunCertPathBuilderException: unable to find valid certification path to requested target
```

Answer (score 7, accepted):

I could finally manage to do it with a lot of blind trial and error.

The problem is, by default, the feign builder builds feign clients with null SSLSocketFactory:

**org.springframework.cloud.openfeign.FeignClientsConfiguration#feignBuilder**:

```
@Bean
@Scope("prototype")
@ConditionalOnMissingBean
public Feign.Builder feignBuilder(Retryer retryer) {
    return Feign.builder().retryer(retryer);
}
```

**feign.Feign.Builder**:

```
  public static class Builder {
    // ...
    private Client client = new Client.Default(null, null);
```

So, I had to define this bean in a @Configuration:

```
@Bean
@Profile({"prod", "docker"})
public Feign.Builder feignBuilder() {
    return Feign.builder()
        .retryer(Retryer.NEVER_RETRY)
        .client(new Client.Default(getSSLSocketFactory(), null));
```

with this method: (can't remember source)

```
SSLSocketFactory getSSLSocketFactory() {
    char[] allPassword = keyStorePassword.toCharArray();
    SSLContext sslContext = null;
    try {
        sslContext = SSLContextBuilder
            .create()
            .setKeyStoreType(keyStoreType)
            .loadKeyMaterial(ResourceUtils.getFile(keyStore), allPassword, allPassword)
            .build();
    } catch (Exception e) { /* *** */ }
    return sslContext.getSocketFactory();
}
```

Now, it works for me, I debugged though the feign client calls and the sslSocketFactory is correctly passed to the underlying connection.

Comment: where are all the keyStorePassword, keyStoreType, keyStore variables coming from?

Comment: a straightforward way is to store values in application.properties/yml and pass them into the fields `keyStorePassword, keyStoreType, keyStore` of a class annotated with [`@ConfigurationProperties`](https://docs.spring.io/spring-boot/docs/current/api/org/springframework/boot/context/properties/ConfigurationProperties.html)

Comment: I assume u are using spring-cloud-starter-openfeign.  So from the above, can i conclude that by default, passing in javax.net.ssl.keyStore=path_to_cert.p12 -Djavax.net.ssl.keyStorePassword=xxx -Djavax.net.ssl.keyStoreType=PKCS12  is useless, unless we manually do what u does above to create  a sslSocketFactory.  Wonder if there is any other alternative way for client to configure openfeign to use SSL, without having to write a single line of code, but purely via adding some settings to the configuration file.

Comment: The credentials are indeed store in properties, and bound with @Value. This was +2 years ago, maybe there have been changes to simply this since then

Answer (score 4):

In case you wish to achieve the above effect programmatically without using keytool, you can do the following:

```kotlin
class CustomFeignConfiguration {

    private val log = Logger.getLogger(this.javaClass.name)

    @Value("\${client_p12_base64_encoded_string}")
    private val clientP12: String = ""

    @Value("\${client_p12_password}")
    private val clientP12Pass: String = ""

    @Bean
    fun feignClient(): Client {
        val sslSocketFactory= getSSLSocketFactory()
        log.info("CUSTOM FEIGN CLIENT CALLED")
        return Client.Default(sslSocketFactory, DefaultHostnameVerifier())
    }

    private fun getSSLSocketFactory(): SSLSocketFactory {
        val decoder = java.util.Base64.getDecoder()
        val p12 = decoder.decode(clientP12)
        val p12File = File("clientCer.p12")
        p12File.writeBytes(p12)

        try {
            val sslContext = SSLContexts
                .custom()
                .loadKeyMaterial(p12File, clientP12Pass.toCharArray(), clientP12Pass.toCharArray())
                .build()
            return sslContext.socketFactory
        } catch (exception: Exception) {
            throw RuntimeException(exception)
        }

    }
}
```

The FeignClient interface that is using the configuration has to load this specifically

```kotlin
@FeignClient(name = "client", configuration = [CustomFeignConfiguration::class], url = "\${url}")
interface Client {
  ....
  ....
}
```

The SSLContexts library can only use p12 certificates and we have to convert the certificates and keys in PEM format to the P12 format.

Create a p12 certificate from your PEM certificate and key using the following SSL command:

```shell
openssl pkcs12 -export -inkey domain.key -in domain.crt -out domain.p12
```

Please record the password that you enter after you run this command.

Convert this p12 certificate to a base64 string using the following command

```shell
base64 domain.p12 > domain.p12.base64
```

Convert this multiline string to a single line string using the following command:

```shell
tr -d "\n\r" < domain.p12.base64 > domain.p12.base64.singleline
```

Use the single line string from this command and the password that you recorded earlier in your **application.properties**.

Answer (score 1):

In contrast to @BiAiB's answer, In case someone is facing the same issue in 2023. I configured the Client as a Bean in Feign Configurations and set SSL Socket Factory details there.

Gradle Imports:

```
implementation 'org.springframework.cloud:spring-cloud-starter-openfeign:3.1.6'
implementation 'io.github.openfeign:feign-httpclient:12.3'
```

Client Bean in Feign Configuration:

```
@Bean
public Client feignClient() throws Exception {
    log.info("Configuring SSL Context for Feign Client");
    return new Client.Default(createSSLContext(), SSLConnectionSocketFactory.getDefaultHostnameVerifier());
}
```

and created SSL Socket Factory for from resource files as follow:

```
private SSLSocketFactory createSSLContext() throws Exception {
    String trustStorePath = "classpath:cacerts"
    String keyStorePath = "classpath:client-key.pfx"

    log.info("Trust Store for Feign Client: " + trustStorePath);
    log.info("Key Store for Feign Client: " + keyStorePath);

    KeyStore keyStore = KeyStore.getInstance("PKCS12"); // PKCS12 for PFX files. Change this to 'JKS' if you are using java keystore
    keyStore.load(new FileInputStream(ResourceUtils.getFile(keyStorePath)), keyStorePassword.toCharArray());

    SSLContext context = SSLContextBuilder.create()
            .loadTrustMaterial(ResourceUtils.getFile(trustStorePath), trustStorePassword.toCharArray())
            .loadKeyMaterial(keyStore, keyStorePassword.toCharArray())
            .build();
    return context.getSocketFactory();
}
```