# Using ssl certificate with feign

Tags: java, spring, spring-boot, ssl, spring-cloud-feign

I'm trying to acess a apllication secured by https, i have a p12 certificate (already imported as .cer into cacerts folder of my jdk).

I already tried this tutorial to no success:
https://dzone.com/articles/ssl-based-feignclient-example-in-java-microcervice

And also i'm using part of this solution:
[How to use p12 client certificate with spring feign client](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/58059632/how-to-use-p12-client-certificate-with-spring-feign-client)

Debuging the ssl connection i get the following error:
`javax.net.ssl|ERROR|25|http-nio-auto-1-exec-1|2021-01-26 16:56:34.789 BRT|TransportContext.java:317|Fatal (HANDSHAKE_FAILURE): Received fatal alert: handshake_failure`

My current feign config class

```
    @Bean
    @ConditionalOnMissingBean
    public Feign.Builder feignBuilder(Retryer retryer) {
        return Feign.builder().retryer(retryer);
    }
    
    @Bean
    public Feign.Builder feignBuilder() {
        return Feign.builder()
            .retryer(Retryer.NEVER_RETRY)
            .client(new Client.Default(getSSLSocketFactory(), null));
    }
    
    private SSLSocketFactory getSSLSocketFactory() {
        String keyStorePassword = "myPassword";
        char[] allPassword = keyStorePassword.toCharArray();
        SSLContext sslContext = null;
        try {
            sslContext = SSLContextBuilder
                .create()
                .setKeyStoreType("PKCS12")
                .loadKeyMaterial(ResourceUtils.getFile("keypath"), allPassword, allPassword)
                .build();
        } catch (Exception e) {  }
        return sslContext.getSocketFactory();
    }
```

In the debbuging section of the code i can see my certificate is there, but still my java is getting the handshake error. I'm new to ssl concept and possible did some config wrong.

One last note, when in the feign config class and set the trust store and password by System

```
         System.setProperty("javax.net.ssl.trustStorePassword", "pass");
        System.setProperty("javax.net.ssl.trustStore", "pathtocerth.p12");
```

The error change to this:

`javax.net.ssl|ERROR|25|http-nio-auto-1-exec-1|2021-01-26 16:48:58.551 BRT|TransportContext.java:317|Fatal (CERTIFICATE_UNKNOWN): PKIX path building failed: sun.security.provider.certpath.SunCertPathBuilderException: unable to find valid certification path to requested target`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I'm answering myself since i found out the problem. Case someone face the same issue the solution is quite simple.

Inside application properties you need to add these properties:

```
feign.httpclient.disableSslValidation=true
feign.httpclient.enabled=false
feign.okhttp.enabled=true
```

From

```
<dependency>
    <groupId>io.github.openfeign</groupId>
    <artifactId>feign-httpclient</artifactId>
    <version>9.4.0</version>
</dependency>
```

Set the feign configuration class

```
@Configuration
public class CustomFeignConfiguration {

    @Bean
    public void Config() {  
        System.setProperty("javax.net.ssl.keyStoreType", "PKCS12");    
        System.setProperty("javax.net.ssl.keyStore", "path to p12");  
        System.setProperty("javax.net.ssl.keyStorePassword", "key password"); 
    }
```

And use the feign config in the feign request

```
@FeignClient(name = "foo", url = "https://foo/foo",
configuration = CustomFeignConfiguration.class)
public interface IFeingRequest {

request here

}
```

With this solution I did NOT need to convert the certificate and store it into java trust store.

Comment: I think this is wrong because you are setting the default keystore

Comment: why are you disabling ssl validation

Comment: I was going to say the same as George. This is not a solution. You are actually disabling SSL validation.

Comment: this is very incorrect :) its disabling SSL validation

Answer (score 3):

In case someone is facing the same issue in 2023. I configured the Client as a Bean in Feign Configurations and set SSL Socket Factory details there.

Gradle Imports:

```
implementation 'org.springframework.cloud:spring-cloud-starter-openfeign:3.1.6'
implementation 'io.github.openfeign:feign-httpclient:12.3'
```

Client Bean in Feign Configuration:

```
@Bean
public Client feignClient() throws Exception {
    log.info("Configuring SSL Context for Feign Client");
    return new Client.Default(createSSLContext(), SSLConnectionSocketFactory.getDefaultHostnameVerifier());
}
```

and created SSL Socket Factory for from resource files as follow:

```
private SSLSocketFactory createSSLContext() throws Exception {
    String trustStorePath = "classpath:cacerts"
    String keyStorePath = "classpath:client-key.pfx"

    log.info("Trust Store for Feign Client: " + trustStorePath);
    log.info("Key Store for Feign Client: " + keyStorePath);

    KeyStore keyStore = KeyStore.getInstance("PKCS12"); // PKCS12 for PFX files. Change this to 'JKS' if you are using java keystore
    keyStore.load(new FileInputStream(ResourceUtils.getFile(keyStorePath)), keyStorePassword.toCharArray());

    SSLContext context = SSLContextBuilder.create()
            .loadTrustMaterial(ResourceUtils.getFile(trustStorePath), trustStorePassword.toCharArray())
            .loadKeyMaterial(keyStore, keyStorePassword.toCharArray())
            .build();
    return context.getSocketFactory();
}
```

Answer (score 0):

You can add the key (and additional trust store optionally) directly via application properties in Spring.

```
server:
  ssl:
    #trust-store: path_to_your_truststore
    #trust-store-password: changeit
    #trust-store-type: JKS
    #trust-store-provider: SUN
    key-store: path_to_your_keystore
    key-store-password: changeit
    key-alias: 1
    key-store-type: PKCS12
    key-store-provider: SUN
    key-password: changeit
    protocol: TLS
```

To identify the key-alias, key-store-type and key-store-provider, you can use the following command:

```
keytool -list -keystore  path_to_keystore
```

But if you just want to turn off hostname verification, then you don't need above. You can configure it for feign httpclient by adding these properties:

```
feign.httpclient.disableSslValidation=true
```

and this maven dependency:

```
<dependency>
    <groupId>io.github.openfeign</groupId>
    <artifactId>feign-httpclient</artifactId>
</dependency>
```

No need for okhttp.

Comment: Thanks. May i ask, is it possible to configure and enable HTTPS on openfeign without using another library (feign-httpclient form io.github.openfeign)

Comment: If no library is provided as maven dependency, then openfeign will use some client it has configured by default. In this case however, some of the configuration parameters like disableSslValidation won't work.

Answer (score 0):

This issue has to do with the fact that this specific cert is not included in the trusted certificates store.
For development purposes we can create an accepting TrustStrategy like this:

```
TrustStrategy acceptingTrustStrategy = (cert, authType) -> true;
```

and then using it like this directly in the SSLContextBuilder:

```
.loadTrustMaterial(null, acceptingTrustStrategy)
```